# Is a feature branch merged into the master branch, or the opposite?

Tags: git, github

On GitHub, after I created a pull request from my feature branch, Github showed that

```
tim  wants to merge 5 commits into master from feature
```

Then I resolved some merge conflict, and GitHub showed that

```
Merge branch 'master' into feature
```

Now I am confused, because the pull request I created is for merging my feature branch into the master branch. Why does GitHub said the opposite? How shall I understand the two contradictory statements on GitHub?

Thanks.

Comment: In git terms, it doesn't matter, AFAIK. It will end up being the same revision with the same two parents.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that If branch A is merged into branch B, then branch B continues to exist while branch A stops to exist? So isn't it different when switching the role of branch A and B?

Comment: The general idea is you have a main branch such as master and other feature branches. You should always merge feature-branches to master. After that's done you should generally remove the feature branch so that you'll always have a base (main) branch such as master to create a new feature branch from rather than the other way round.

Comment: @SaugatAcharya I agree with what you said. But how shall i understand the two contradictory statements on GitHub?

Comment: I don't think either one of the branches ceases to exist. If you are working on branch A and you merge B a new revision is created and branch A reference is moved to this new pointer. If you had been working on B it's basically the same result only that branch B would be pointing to the new revision.

Comment: That's not a contradictory statement. First of all to merge something into master your feature-branch has to be up-to-date with the master branch. So when you try to merge something into master and it showed that you have some merge conflicts. It generally means that there are new changes to master and you need to pull the master branch to your feature branch. Thus the message `Merge branch 'master' into feature`. Now you'll have to merge the feature branch back to master after the conflict has been resolved.

Comment: Of course, that's "technically speaking". It is "better" for consistency's sake to merge feature branches into master, for example. But it's not a technical problem, say.

Comment: The thing is you'll generally need a base branch to make feature branches from. Technically you can do anything you like.

Comment: @SaugatAcharya: Thanks. Do you mean that in the second step, I need to "merge the feature branch back to master after the conflict has been resolved" in the first step? On GitHub, I have already resolved the conflict, and Github said that "Merge branch 'master' into feature". Then what shall i do to "merge the feature branch back to master"?

Comment: Yes, you need to merge the feature branch back to master. Look at the answer by Anthony below, it says the same.

Comment: @Edmundo "In git terms, it doesn't matter" This is not correct. Merging from branch A into branch B is different than than merging from B into A. In many situations, particularly when there are no merge conflicts, the final result is the same. But there are some situations where this is not the case.

Comment: @Saugat but on GitHub, after I resolved the conflict,  Github said that "Merge branch 'master' into feature", I don't see anything that I can do, and GitHub doesn't tell me what to do next either.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice well, this is very interesting and it flies in the face of my basic assumptions of how git works. Can you find an example out there in the wild (a github project or something like that) where if I merge two revisions using one and the other as the checked out version you get different results? If my assumptions are right you will end up with either 1 - no conflicts and results are exactly the same or 2 - conflicts that "mirror" each other.

Comment: @Tim Code-Apprentice has explained it nicely below. You'll have to push the feature branch after fixing the conflicts and now the pull request should show a green "Merge Pull Request" button.

Comment: @Tim Typically, you make a pull request to a repository owned by someone else. You must wait for feedback from the owner of the original project. After you make the improvements requested, the owner will then accept your pull request and merge it into their repo.

Comment: @SaugatAcharya The "Merge Pull Request" will only appear if Tim owns the repo where the pull request was made...which is probably not a valid assumption.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, I was just explaining.

Comment: @Edmundo I vaguely recall a situation where merging branch A into branch B had conflicts but merging branch B into A did not. I'll see if I can come up with an example (probably contrived).

Comment: @Edmundo As I think about it more, what you say makes sense. The commit graph will be the same in each case. The only differences will will be which commit each branch points to and the parent ordering when using `HEAD^`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably resolved some merge conflicts when merging with github.  github shows resolution of merge conflicts on the feature branch itself (generally a best practice when resolving conflicts is to resolve them in the feature branch) and then merged the feature branch into master.

Here's a diagram:

```
master  A - B - C
         \   \ /
feature   E - F
```

The `F` commit (where conflicts where resolved) is the `Merge branch 'master' into feature` commit.  The `C` commit (if it exists -- github may choose to fast-forward your feature branch onto master) is the merge of the feature branch into master. [More information on what "fast forward" means](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

At the end, the master branch history will look something like:

```
master A - E - B - F - C
```

Comment: I disagree with the last statement. The non-linear original example is not the same as the linear final version.

Comment: I'm sure you know that a branch is just a pointer to a commit. Can you modify your diagrams to show which commit each branch points to? So in the first diagram, `master` points to commit C and `feature` points to commit `F`. IMO, the way you have it now seems misleading. (Or maybe I'm just used to the branch name after the commit names in diagrams similar to these...)

Comment: I'm not sure which parts are misleading -- time goes left to right and the commits "on the branch" are listed in the row of the branch name

Comment: Yah, it's probably just me.

Answer (score 1):

A pull request is an attempt to merge your feature branch into the project's `master` branch. Often, there will be merge conflicts that must be resolved manually. When you do so, you should merge the current `master` into your feature branch. The commit message you see will say exactly this. When the Pull Request is finalized, then you will also see a commit with the message "Merge Pull Request #XYZ from user/branch".

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that resolving conflict has two steps: the first one is to merge the master into the feature branch, and the second one is to merge the feature into the master? If resolving conflict happens on GitHub, do I only need to do the first step, and then GitHub will automatically do the second step and when it finishes it will show  the message "Merge Pull Request #XYZ from user/branch"?  Does the message mean that merging of the feature to master finishes?

Comment: If resolving conflict happens on my local machine, do i need to do the two steps explicitly, rather than just the first step? What commands can I use to do the two steps?

Comment: @Tim After you resolve merge conflicts locally, you need to push the new commit to your own GitHub repo. This will automatically update the Pull Request with the merge commit. Then you should wait for feedback from the owner of the original repo. They will most likely request some improvements in order for your PR to meet their standards. Make the improvements and push again. This process can go back and forth for as many cycles as the owner requires.

Comment: @Tim Once the PR meets the owner's standards, they will merge the PR into their own master branch which is when you will see a commit with the message "Merge Pull Request #XYZ from user/branch". If you want to continue contributing, you should always keep your own local `master` and your fork's `master` up to date with the original repo. See [this documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) for details.